# how to manage event listeners in for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3

For loop contains an event listener function. but loop iteration is quicker than listener function.Before the listener function completes next iteration starts. how to handle this???

Comment: Got some example code..? Can't decipher your goal.

Comment: @user732251 what do you mean the "loop iteration is quicker than the listener function"? Do you mean the event listener you add to your object doesn't recieve an event before the next object in the loop has an event listener added to it? If your having trouble describing the problem in your question then you should post some code or describe the purpose of your project at least. I'm also curious to know why you would need that kind of functionality in the first place.

Comment: @user732251 Should elaborate on your question. Provide some code example, just that "for-loop" you speak of could help us, as Marty puts it - decipher your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't need a "for" loop.

According to your description, it looks like you need some form of event chain where after the first event complete you set up a new listener and so on...

Answer (score 1):

If the answer your looking for is as PatrickS described, I've create an example of how to implement it:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _queue:Queue;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var queueItems:Vector.<QueueItem> = new Vector.<QueueItem>();

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var timer:Timer = new Timer(2 * 1000, 1);

                queueItems.push(new QueueItem(timer, TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete));

            }// end for

            _queue = new Queue(queueItems);

            var currentTimer:Timer = Timer(_queue.currentQueueItem.eventDispatcher);
            currentTimer.start();

            _queue.shift();

        }// end function

        private function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if (_queue.currentQueueItem)
            {
                var currentTimer:Timer = Timer(_queue.currentQueueItem.eventDispatcher);
                currentTimer.start();

                if (_queue.length > 0) _queue.shift();

            }// end if

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
import flash.events.Event;

internal class Queue
{
    private var _queueItems:Vector.<QueueItem>;

    public function get currentQueueItem():QueueItem { return (_queueItems.length > 0) ? _queueItems[0] : null }
    public function get length():int { return _queueItems.length }

    public function Queue(queueItems:Vector.<QueueItem>) 
    {
        _queueItems = queueItems;

    }// end function

    public function shift():void
    {
        var eventDispatcher:IEventDispatcher = _queueItems[0].eventDispatcher;
        var type:String = _queueItems[0].type;
        var listener:Function = _queueItems[0].listener;
        var useCapture:Boolean = _queueItems[0].useCapture;
        var priority:int = _queueItems[0].priority;
        var useWeakReference:Boolean = _queueItems[0].useWeakReference;

        eventDispatcher.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);

        _queueItems.shift();

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class QueueItem
{
    private var _eventDispatcher:IEventDispatcher;
    private var _type:String;
    private var _listener:Function;
    private var _useCapture:Boolean;
    private var _priority:int;
    private var _useWeakReference:Boolean;

    public function get eventDispatcher():IEventDispatcher { return _eventDispatcher }
    public function get type():String { return _type}
    public function get listener():Function { return _listener }
    public function get useCapture():Boolean { return _useCapture }
    public function get priority():int { return _priority }
    public function get useWeakReference():Boolean { return _useWeakReference }

    public function QueueItem(eventDispatcher:IEventDispatcher, type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false)
    {
        _eventDispatcher = eventDispatcher;
        _type = type;
        _listener = listener;
        _useCapture = useCapture;
        _priority = priority;
        _useWeakReference = useWeakReference;

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Simply put, this creates a queue like system that adds an event listener to the `IEventListener` object at the front of the queue and when its added the queue is shifted.

The above shows how you can use this with `Timer` objects.